# SQL: Collation conflict between two different collations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

I am having trouble with this error

> "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."  in SSMS.

I know this means my columns are not having the same collation and i have looked up for a solution and tried changing the collation. They both have the same collation but I still get the same error.

How do i fix it?
This is my script :

```
`INSERT INTO EVoucherBatchMapping_New(EVoucherBatchValidityID,
                                    EventCode,
                                    ArrivalDate,
                                    DepartureDate,
                                    NoShowCharge)
SELECT                              EVoucherBatchValidityID,
                                    EventCode,
                                    ArrivalDate,
                                    DepartureDate,
                                    NoShowCharge
 FROM EVoucherBatchMapping
WHERE ArrivalDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PromotionEvent_New where EVoucherBatchMapping.EventCode = PromotionEvent_New.EventCode) `
```

Comment: Seems like EVoucherBatchMapping.EventCode and PromotionEvent_New.EventCode are defined with different collations. Fix the table definitions!

Comment: Omg, it works. I change the wrong collation, instead i changed the one in evoucherbatchmapping_new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter the column definitions to use the same collation or give the collation you want to use in the sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM PromotionEvent_New 
WHERE 
EVoucherBatchMapping.EventCode = PromotionEvent_New.EventCode
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM PromotionEvent_New 
WHERE 
EVoucherBatchMapping.EventCode = PromotionEvent_New.EventCode
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already altered the mismatch collation using:  ` ALTER TABLE YourTableName
  ALTER COLUMN OffendingColumn
    VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL`